# Google Maps complex polygon not showing when polygon has 15,000+ sets of coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, polygons

I'm using the Google Maps API (V3) and I'm having some trouble displaying polygons that have **15,000 points** or so, with at least **10 points of precision** in each point.  These are weather and county maps, so naturally the amount of data is quite high.  It should be noted that I'm able to display a simple polygon right now, and am using the same measures to add the ones with large amounts of data, and looking at it in the JS console, I can see that it's getting populated.

Does anyone have experience dealing with something like this where (presumably), the amount of data is playing a role, and I'm hitting some limit that I can't seem to find documented anywhere?

Is there a better method that I can use instead of just declaring a `new google.maps.Polygon`  with a massive amount of points contained within?

---

***UPDATE:*** The code that I'm using is below.  Memory usage when the page is up is around 160MB in Chrome, and I'm okay with that.  When the script is running, there's only a few MB spike for maybe 2 seconds.

```
function addPolygonToMap(WeatherAlert) {
  WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert.googleCoordinateArray = [];
  if(WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert.Coordinates.length > 0){
    // WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert.Coordinates contains a string of all the coordinates.
    $.each(WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert.Coordinates, function(key, value) {
      // CleanPolygonData splits the coordinates and separates them further into an X and Y value.
      var PolygonData = CleanPolygonData(value);
      $.each(PolygonData, function(key, Polygon) {
        WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert.googleCoordinateArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Polygon[0], Polygon[1]));
      });
    });  
  }

  var HexColor = mapWeatherAlerts(WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert, window.WeatherAlertProperties);

  var Polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    WeatherAlert: WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert,
    paths: WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert.googleCoordinateArray,
    strokeColor: '#' + HexColor,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#' + HexColor,
    fillOpacity: 0.4
  });

  Polygon.setMap(map);

  window.MapPolygons.push(Polygon);

  google.maps.event.addListener(Polygon, 'click', clickPolygon);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  And at least post in the question the code that you are using to display the polygons that have issues somewhere?  What does the memory usage of your browser look like when you encounter the issue?

Comment: 10 points of precision is 0.011132 mm at the equator. A bit of overkill

Comment: @davidstrachan Thanks for the information.  That seems like quite a bit of overkill.  I could probably get away with a few miles of variation, honestly.  I'll probably just truncate the data to 2-3 decimal points.

Comment: @geocodezip I've included the code in question.  It's not perfect (for example, `WeatherAlert.WeatherAlert` will be simplified to `WeatherAlert`).  If you need some sample data, I can upload some to Google Drive.  Basically, this function takes in a `WeatherAlert` object, which contains just a string of all of the coordinates.  `CleanPolygonData` just breaks those out to X and Y coordinates.  Beyond that, I think it should be pretty standard to Google's examples, and pretty self explanatory.  I appreciate the help, so please let me know if I can provide any further information to help.

Comment: I've reduced it down to two points of precision, but unfortunately, that does not fix the issue.